# Refresh pip installed packages

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am doing an installation script that does a complete installation of a software with it's needed modules on an Ubuntu  server where i import the pip module then check for installed packages then install what i need then i check for them again.

The problem is when i install the new packages changes are not reflected to the imported pip module in the same run.

I am using:

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

so i want to know is there any way that i could possibly clear pip cache or refresh modules?