# pip install package programmatically and then import it without restart

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I am installing a python package from a running Python code using the reliable subprocess.popen()

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', <path to package wheel>, '--upgrade'], text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I am trying to import the module using `importlib`. This call fails and requires the server to be restarted to be able to load the newly installed module. Is threre any way to dynamically reload the modules in the thread?

I found a similar question that has failed to elicit any response :( [Refresh pip installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770229/refresh-pip-installed-packages)
Appreciate if someone can help or guide.

Comment: maybe python-autoreload

Comment: autoreload seems to be for an already loaded module @Johnny. 
Similarly, `importlib` offers a reload function but it is also for an already loaded module. My use-case is to install a new package and then import the module within a running piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_spec` does that job. It looks for the package if it does not find an entry in `sys.modules`.

```
importlib.util.find_spec(module_name, package=None)
```